# Snap issues with "Selection to Active"

Tags: snapping

Using the snap option I have frequently issues with the option "Selection to Active".
If I use it first both, selected and active item snap together somewhere around the median point of each other. After undoing and using the option again it mostly works fine.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: I can't tell if this is a known bug... never saw this question here and never experienced it myself. Just tested it in my Blender (version 3.3.1) and it works as expected, snapping to the active object. If you suspect it is a bug and not a feature, it might be relevant which version you are using to check if we experience this as well. And if it is a bug you should file a bug report (_Help_ > _Report a Bug_).

Comment: Does it possibly have something to do with the fact that each of the objects in question has children? The children themselves are not selected, because these would then also jump to the origin point of the active object - UNWANTED!

Comment: No, it shouldn't and in my Blender it doesn't change anything. Still don't know which version you have to determine if this is version-dependent.

Comment: When I get home I will provide the blend-file and return to you. Perhaps I manage to get a screen capture to show the problem.